# Was it Barry's reflection or himself after the time jump?

Tags: plot-explanation, arrowverse, the-flash

It's regarding the last episode of Season 1 of ***'The Flash'*** TV series. ["Fast Enough"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_Flash_%282014_TV_series%29_episodes) .

When ***Barry*** aka '***The Flash***' was running to the morgue he saw his reflection which he mentioned to ***Dr Wells*** aka ***Eobard Thawne*** that he felt like it was him who he saw.

So, my question is, can that be he himself after that time jump shown at the end of the episode? This is just what I thought at once and I need some opinions on that.

Comment: Are you talking about the last episode of season 1 here or the "last" episode as measured from the time of asking. In the latter case, could you be a little more exact which episode that was?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's him. He broke the time barrier and jumped back to past. From IMDb

> Mark creates a Tsunami that could destroy the city and Barry shows
> Iris his powers. Barry tries to go as fast he could to create a wall
> of wind and **accidentally time travels back in time** to where he was
> trying to get to the morgue.

And from the conversation it's clear it's him

> Dr. Harrison Wells: You ruptured the time continuum, didn't you?
> You're experiencing temporal reversion. Barry Allen: Yeah! Dr.
>
> Harrison Wells: How long?
>
> Barry Allen: Uh, a day and some change. It's
> like I'm living it all over again.
>
> Dr. Harrison Wells: Yeah, well,
> that's good. That means there's not too much you could've messed up
> yet. How did this happen?
>
> Barry Allen: I-I don't know. I mean, I was
> running faster than I've ever ran, and the first time that I lived
> this day some really horrible things happened. There was a tidal wave
> and...